# Any Smalltalk on .NET?

Tags: .net, smalltalk

Are there any usable implementations of Smalltalk for the .NET runtime?

Answer (score 6):

There's a project to build Smalltalk on top of the DLR. Unsurprisingly, it's called [IronSmaltalk](http://www.codeplex.com/IronSmalltalk).

Answer (score 0):

There is [LSW Vision-Smalltalk](http://www.lesser-software.com/lswvst.htm), which seems to be a private Smalltalk environment, they claim to support .NET:

"LSWVST has a .NET Integration which enables us to develop our .NET Tools. LSWVST includes now LSW DotNet-Lab a toolset for .NET programmiing. We have created a "pure .NET experimental Smalltalk ( LSWVST.Net )."

you may have to ask privately for a downloadable copy.